# How to create android app which change the speech to text language when button click

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I wanted to create an app which changes the default android system text-to-speech language when clicking a button. Why I need that? Because I am using this app for blind people. So for registration and login, I need the English language but when they enter the app then language should differ (Bangla).

So please if anyone can help me? Let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Cloud Speech API.
Google Cloud Speech-to-Text enables developers to convert audio to text by applying powerful neural network models in an easy-to-use API

Please note following Points

- Not free.
- Supports 80 different languages
- Recognize audio uploaded in the request.
- Works with apps across any device and platform.

Details:https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/

Price: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtSpeechInput;
private ImageButton btnSpeak;
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    // hide the action bar
    getActionBar().hide();

    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    });

}

// Showing google speech input dialog
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


//Receiving speech input
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
}
```